# What is the difference between DbContext.Add() and DbContext.DbSet<TEntity>.Add(TEntity)? When do you use one vs the other?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

In ms docs [**Razor pages** tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud) the DbContext has a DbSet Students set

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

and in the OnPostAsync() method creates and then adds updated students using `DbSet<TEntity>.Add(TEntity)` method[(documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.add?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet%601.Add);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-2.0):

```
var emptyStudent = new Student();
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
    emptyStudent,
    "student",   // Prefix for form value.
    s => s.FirstMidName, s => s.LastName, s => s.EnrollmentDate))
{
    _context.Students.Add(emptyStudent);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

---

The [MVC tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud) also has a `DbContext` that has a DbSet Students however in the StudentsController.cs Create() post method, it adds students directly calling [DbContext.add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add%60%601);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-2.0) on the DbContext:

```
_context.Add(student); 
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The only other difference I see is that in MVC the student was passed in as a parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate")] Student student) {
```

---

Is there any difference between the two? Can they be used interchangeably. When to use one or the other?

Comment: To answer the second question of when to use one or the other: I would say `_context.Students.Add(student)` is a bit clearer since it looks like you are adding a student to the student collection. But basically, it’s up to you what you prefer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the [sources](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore) you can find out the implementation of [`InternalDbSet`'s](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/dev/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs) (which is a concrete implementation of the abstract `DbSet`) `Add` method:

```
public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Add(TEntity entity)
        => _context.Add(entity);
```

which clearly means that it's just a facade over `DbContext`s `Add`.

Technically this means that both do exactly the same.

Comment: I would've guessed the opposite was true (that the context would call the DbSet's add method.) since there are several DbSets inside of DbContext. Guess I need to look up DbContext.add() to find out why(probably I will have to wait a few weeks when I reach EF documentation for it to make sense).

Comment: To explain quickly: Every entity that is fetched from the database or added to it is stored within the database context and changes to it are tracked. Adding a new entity just means to tell the context to start tracking that now. So there is actually very little going on when you add an entity, it just causes an entry to be added to the context’s change tracker.

Comment: @poke always remember to @ comments so the OP also gets notified.

Comment: @poke I see. It's doing something similar to the line `        _context.Entry(studentToDelete).State = EntityState.Deleted;` but for adding. How the Entries are represented I guess I will have to wait to understand.

Comment: According to official documentation, this is also valid for Entity Framework 6: _"`DbSet.Add(Object)` Method: Adds the given entity to the context underlying the set (...)"_ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.add?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). `DbContext.Add` is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add?view=efcore-2.1.

Comment: The source looks different now: it's no longer calling `DbContext.Add()`. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/53fbd042296b30c8093168485fb9ca29544b5f07/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs#L199

Answer (score 4):

The source now looks a bit different from Wiktor's answer, but the [docs provide this statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/miscellaneous):

> Many methods, including `Add`, `Update`, `Attach`, and `Remove`, have
> implementations on both DbSet and DbContext. These methods
> have *exactly the same behavior* for normal entity types.
>
> ...
>
> The exception to this rule is when using shared-type entity types,
> which were introduced in EF Core 5.0, primarily for many-to-many join
> entities.